# Integrate probability of derivative with respect to time to find probability with respect to time

Tags: probability, derivatives, random-variables

I'm currently working on modelling systems with both continuous and discrete random variables that operate in continuous time, and I've run into a problem that I don't know how to solve or search for on a search engine.  I've also not encountered anything quite like it in any of my math classes in all my years in college, so I don't know what domain this sort of problem belongs to or what the proper terminology or notation is.

I have a random variable $X$ that varies with time $t$.  I have a probability density function of the form $P \left[ \frac{d X}{d t} = \frac{d x}{d t} | X = x \right] (t)$.  This is meant to represent the probability that the *derivative* of $X$ is $\frac{d x}{d t}$ at time $t$, given that the current value of $X$ is $x$.  Let's assume that I can integrate and differentiate this function.

I ultimately want to know how to obtain $P \left[ X = x \right] (t)$ (or the probability that $X$ has value $x$ at time $t$).  I have the initial conditions $P \left[ X = x \right] (0)$.  I would like to take the approach of finding $\frac{d P \left [ X = x \right] (t)}{d t}$ and then integrating, if possible.

Is it possible to obtain $\frac{d P \left[ X = x \right] (t)}{d t}$ from $P \left[ \frac{d X}{d t} = \frac{d x}{d t} | X = x \right] (t)$?  I suspect that it is not, but I'd love to be wrong.

If so, how?

If not, how else might I obtain $P \left[ X = x \right] (t)$ from $P \left[ \frac{d X}{d t} = \frac{d x}{d t} | X = x \right] (t)$?

I'd like answers that generalize to dealing with higher order derivatives and systems of equations that relate multiple random variables.  In addition, some context on what domain this sort of problem belongs to would be appreciated.

EDIT: I clarified a bit what I'm asking for.  I realized that I had some conditional probability in my problem, which might make things easier or harder.

I can construct a recursive expression that seems like it would be a step toward obtaining $P \left[ X = x \right] (t)$ directly, but I am then confronted with an integral that I don't see how to solve.

$$
P \left[ X = x \right] (t) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} P \left[ X = p \right] (t - d t) \cdot P \left[ \frac{d X}{d t} = \frac{x - p}{d t} | X = p \right] (t - d t) \cdot d p
$$